# Absolute bottom position in scroll div?

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76gbfrah/)

I wish to align my buttons to the base of the container so I use:

```
.buttons{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

This is fine for when there is not much content (the pink div in the fiddle), but when there is a lot of content (the orange div in the fiddle), the container scrolls and the buttons are not at the bottom of the container.

How can I have it so that the buttons are at the bottom of the container when it doesn't have a lot of content and they are at the bottom of the scroll (below the content) when there is a lot of content.

Comment: Instead position absolute set them to `position:relative;`

Comment: @LuisP.A. thanks but does not answer question.

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes thanks but this doesnt answer the question - in the orange box the buttons should be below the content - at the bottom of the scroll.

Comment: @Vitorinofernandes still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `height:100%`to html and body and then `min-height:100%`to your container like this (I have added a few more lines to make it look better):

```
body, html {height:100%; margin:0;}

* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.container{
    min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
    padding-bottom:30px;
}
p {margin:0;}

.buttons{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

.pink{
    background: pink;
}

.tomato{
    background: tomato;
}
```

Here you have the **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/76gbfrah/6/)**

(add more content to check it out)

**EDITED (fixed height)**
Same concept just adding another container to use the `min-height`

**[NEW FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/76gbfrah/12/)**

Comment: Ummm... I did it thinking about a full height container. Maybe not valid if you need multiples one. Let me know and I may think another way.

Comment: Thanks but I need the container to be 200px in height.

Comment: Amazing the fast triggered ridiculous downvotes. I have edited my answer to fit your set height

Answer (score 1):

I added an .inner container that has a min-height. If the content in there is low, then the .inner container will push your buttons to the bottom. If the content is more, then the .inner container will grow along.

```
.inner {
    min-height: 149px;
}
```

Also note that the buttons have a position relative instead of absolute. When an element is absolute, it does not react to the page contents.

https://jsfiddle.net/76gbfrah/10/

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue because like you said now the buttons are relative and scroll away

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the content in another div with position relative and put the absolute elements you wish to overlay in that parent div. It will act as an overlay of sorts and will ignore the scrolling.